# Sort Scrapy results by url

Tags: python, scrapy

I just started using Scrapy for webscraping a website.I have more than 9000 urls to scrape.

I already tried and it worked, except that I'd like to output results in json files according to the url (if I scraped ten items from url1, I'd like these items in a json object with the url1, same for url2 etc.)

```
{"url1": "www.reddit.com/page1",
 "results1: {
   ["name": "blabla",
    "link": "blabla",
   ],
   ["name": "blabla",
    "link": "blabla",
   ],
   ["name": "blabla",
    "link": "blabla",
   ]
 },

 {"url2": "www.reddit.com/page2",
 "results2: {
   ["name": "blabla",
    "link": "blabla",
   ],
   ["name": "blabla",
    "link": "blabla",
   ],
   ["name": "blabla",
    "link": "blabla",
   ]
 }
```

Is it possible to do this or is it better to scrape the entire site and then sort it after the work ?

My code right now:

```py
import scrapy

class glenmarchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "glenmarch"

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = reversed([
            'https://www.glenmarch.com/cars/results?make=&model=&auction_house_id=&auction_location=&year_start=1913&year_end=1916&low_price=&high_price=&auction_id=&fromDate=&toDate=&keywords=AC+10+HP&show_unsold_cars=0&show_unsold_cars=1?limit=9999',
            'https://www.glenmarch.com/cars/results?make=&model=&auction_house_id=&auction_location=&year_start=1918&year_end=1928&low_price=&high_price=&auction_id=&fromDate=&toDate=&keywords=AC+12+HP&show_unsold_cars=0&show_unsold_cars=1?limit=9999'
        ])


        for url in start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for caritem in response.css("div.car-item-border"):
            yield {
                "model": caritem.css("div.make::text").get(),
                "price": caritem.css("div.price::text").get(),
                "auction": caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").get(),
                "date": caritem.css("div.date::text").get(),
                "auction_url": caritem.css("div.view-auction a::attr(href)").get(),
                "img": caritem.css("img.img-responsive::attr(src)").get()
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using `response.url` wouldn't do the job?

```py
yield {
    "url": response.url,
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Yes it works well but I want to use my "ids" related to my urls to classify the results and I don't know how to import my json file in Scrapy.